# 20V from Dell Precision 3581 USB C/Thunderbolt 4 Port with Power Delivery

Tags: usb, laptop, power-supply, usb-c, usb-power-delivery

USB-PD provides up to 100W of power through the USB-C Port, so I wanted to use 20V power from my Laptop to power my device.
According to the data on the Dell homepage regarding the ports, they are ports with Thunderbolt 4 and **power delivery**. 2 ports are labelled with the lightning bolt for Thunderbolt 4 and the Thunderbolt 4 specification states "*...and up to 15W for computer-powered accessories.*" So if its possible for Thunderbolt to deliver this power, it should also be possible for PD.

Dell Manual regarding Ports Specs:https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/de-de/precision-15-3581-laptop/precision-3581-owners-manual/external-ports?guid=guid-4c4cc1ba-66a4-45f0-8dfc-6013a624ddc0&lang=en-us

I have ordered multiple USB-PD Boards and realized that none of them are compatible with my laptop port, which is why I am unable to obtain 20V from the Port. Although I have spoken to the DELL support team, they haven't provided me with a definitive answer, and it remains unclear whether it is possible or impossible.

My last attempt was on a board called Adafruit USB-C Power Delivery Breakout Board, which has jumpers that enable easy voltage adjustment. I am aware that the majority of applications utilize a USB-PD power adapter. However, in my perspective, it should function in a similar manner due to the port's capability to handle up to 100W and its compatibility with PD.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are the ports actually PD ports? Please list your system's full specs, to begin with, and any other information that may help us better understand your situation.

Comment: @music2myear According to the data on the Dell homepage regarding the ports, they are ports with Thunderbolt 4 and **power delivery**. 2 ports are labelled with the lightning bolt for Thunderbolt 4 and the Thunderbolt 4 specification states "...and up to 15W for computer-powered accessories." So if its possible for Thunderbolt to deliver this power, it should also be possible for PD. Dell Manual regarding Ports Specs:[https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/de-de/precision-15-3581-laptop/precision-3581-owners-manual/external-ports?guid=guid-4c4cc1ba-66a4-45f0-8dfc-6013a624ddc0&lang=en-us]

Comment: Edit your question to put that information in it. While you're editing it, you may also want to break the question out into paragraphs to help make it more readable.

Comment: The key here is “up to”. Just because your laptop can _accept_ 100 W (or more, with proprietary Dell extensions) doesn’t mean it can _put out_ 100 W. Far from it, in fact.